# How to use CONST when there are multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, constants

I'm getting on the `const` train and want to start avoiding `let` at all costs.

The problem I'm seeing is the below case - how would I use `const` in a situation with more than 2 forks in a logic tree?

What's the equivalent pattern with const?

```
function getResult(input) {
    let result;

    switch (input): {
        case (1): { result=x;}
        case (2): { result=y;}
        case (3): { result=x;}
        ...etc
    }

    /*
    ...additional conditionals and functions depending on the outcomes 
    of switch statement
    */    
}
```

thanks,

Comment: `case` does not has braces and curly brackes.

Comment: doing *anything* "at all costs" is a terrible idea.. doing *this* show s a lack of understanding of core js constructs.

Comment: `const` and `let` both have their uses. I think `let` is fine here.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45334143/how-do-i-assign-a-conditional-variable-without-mutation/45334187#45334187

Comment: @NinaScholz It can. It's just a block. It's the colon after `switch (input)` that's wrong.

Comment: @Li357 but wouldnt all blocks execute if `input` is 1 as there is no `break` ?

Comment: @JonasW. Yes, but I was addressing Nina's comment about syntax?

Comment: @NinaScholz they do if you have assignments you want block-scoped.

Comment: @Li357 oh good call,    just rattled this off as a rough example. Thanks

Comment: the standard has no curly brackets inside of `case` statements.

Comment: @NinaScholz  Isn't this just the same as `1 === (1)`  , yes the brackets are redundant and not required, but don't harm and have no effect on the `case` statement.

Comment: @Keith, if the compiler works without, why adding superfluous parts to the code?

Comment: @NinaScholz  because he wants to, some people might think it's easier to read.  In fact Linting packages sometimes hint at you adding more even if not required, you could say it's just a coding style.

Comment: If the curly braces are good enough for eslint recommended ruleset (exclusively with assignments) they're good enough for me

Comment: @Nina From a syntactical POV curly braces are actually unnecessary, however, they can help you visualize a block for each case. So it's a matter of taste, I guess.

Comment: `const` is more appropriate for a functional style that avoids side effects, namely reassignment in your case. `switch` is a statement and you use it in an imperative way so it doesn't work well with `const`.

Comment: @ftor - I'm glad someone gets the issue,  you hit the nail on the head,  which is why I'm looking for alternative patterns so I can ditch let altogether

Comment: @jonasW - oh good call,  those lines definitely should have breaks on them

Comment: Since `break` is not used this all falls through to whatever the last `case` or perhaps `default` does.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 const result = [x,y,x][input - 1];
```

It's an array that's accessed by index.

Comment: The explanation isn't for me. It's for the OP.

Comment: I like this.   Super clean and I could substitute a findindex in a non-numeric case.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with using `let` in this case. `Const` is useful for creating non changing variables throughout the file, function or class. For example, storing a non changing base url for http calls (https://your.domain.here/).

Whereas `let` and `var` are more suited to changing variables such as the amount of time a user clicks on a button, or slider to select a minimum and maximum date/age range.

However, you will want to change your switch statement to a valid statement like so:

```
switch (input) {
    case 1: {
        result=x;
        break;
    }
    case 2: {
        result=y;
        break;
    }
    case 3: {
        result=x;
        break;
    }
    default:
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While I don't necessarily agree with "avoiding `let` at all cost", I'd say the best alternative for using a `switch` statement is to put it in a separate function and use `return`.

The example below shows a pure inner result function that holds the switch logic. Instead of assigning to a variable, it returns a result as soon as it finds a match.

```js
const getInnerResult = (x, y, input) => {
  switch (input) { 
    case 1: 
    case 3:  return x;
    case 2:  return y;
    default: return null; 
  }
}

const getResult = function(input) {
  const result = getInnerResult("a", "b", input);
  
  // Other logic using the `result` variable
  return result ? result.toUpperCase() : "-";
};


console.log(getResult(2));
console.log(getResult(5));
```

Comment: I like this one too,  not quite as terse as the array option but a solid option

Comment: I'm not entirely against the array answer, but in my own code base I wouldn't allow it because: A) It doesn't make its intentions clear, B) It will only work if every case is a `"0"` or `0`-like key, and C) It does not support "overflowing" cases like `1` and `3` both returning `x` without adding `x` to the array twice. One of the benefits of having multiple answers though is that everyone can pick the one that suits their own style/beliefs best :)

Comment: But like I commented you could constant the array,   run findindex on the array  and then apply a similar solution.... But you're right it may be less readable to someone not used to this style of coding.