# Getting error in fetching value of template driven Angular form

Tags: angular, angular-forms

In the register function I am getting the error in storing the value of the form control .

> using "let firstname" , "let lastname"  , "let email" I am getting
>   error  **[tslint] Identifier 'firstName' is never reassigned; use
>   'const' instead of 'let'. (prefer-const)**
>
> Using debugger I am getting error **[tslint] Use of debugger
>   statements is forbidden (no-debugger)**
>
> Also in the console I am getting error  **Cannot read property 'value'
>   of undefined**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-temp-driven',
  templateUrl: './temp-driven.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./temp-driven.component.css']
})
export class TempDrivenComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  register(regForm: any) {
    debugger;
    let firstName =  regForm.control.firstname.value;
    let lastname = regForm.control.lastname.value;
    let email = regForm.control.email.value;

    alert(firstName);
   console.log(regForm);

  }

}
```

Html ->

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-bg">
      <form #regForm ='ngForm' (ngSubmit) ="register(regForm)">
       <h2 class="text-center"> Registeration Form </h2>
      <br/>
      <div class="form-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" name="firstname" ngModel>
      </div>  


      <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="last Name" name="lastname" ngModel>
         </div>  


      <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Eamil Id" name="email" ngModel>
         </div>  

          <br/>

          <div class="align-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="register"> Register </button>
          </div>
          </form>   
      </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is `regForm`? can you add the html?

Comment: I have added please see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Cannot read property 'value' of undefined error

is because

You have written `controls` as `control`. Replace that, It should work.

```
register(regForm: any) {
    debugger;
    let firstName =  regForm.controls.firstname.value;
    let lastname = regForm.controls.lastname.value;
    let email = regForm.controls.email.value;    
   alert(firstName);
   console.log(regForm);    
}
```

You could ignore the first warning, or it is also fine if you change `let` to `const`, because you are not modifying them after they are set.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says you are not using firstName is not assigned to any variable anywhere, just change it to const, it should work fine then,

```
const firstName =  regForm.control.firstname.value;
const lastname = regForm.control.lastname.value;
const email = regForm.control.email.value;
```

the reason for using const is the value wont change inside the code block, while using let will allow the variable to be changed.

Comment: If possible can you explain why we use const instead of let or ver

Comment: @AnuragRanjan its supposedly better to use `const` but its not as you cant reassign the values. see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48503199/how-to-use-const-when-there-are-multiple-conditions/48503850#48503850) where i explain briefly why you would use const

Comment: @mast3rd3mon hope it makes sense now

Comment: hello @Sajeetharan after replacing let with const , I am getting one more error
which says "Cannot read property 'value' of undefined"   .

Answer (score 0):

thanks, I got the bug , here I have used regForm.control   where I have missed the s in control.
so there will be

> let firstName =  regForm.controls.firstname.value;
>       let lastname = regForm.controls.lastname.value;
>       let email = regForm.controls.email.value;

Comment: I have already added an answer to your problem. Why not accept it instead of writing again the same answer yourself.

Answer (score 0):

> For disable **Use of debugger statements is forbidden** warning apply this rule ,n `tsconfig.json`:

```
"rules": {
    "no-debugger": false,
    //... 
}
```